# Combined grouping on two fields

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have access to just the SELECT and WHERE clause to a database. I have no ability to do any more than fill in the blanks between SELECT and FROM and after WHERE ("SELECT _ _ _ _ _ _ FROM TABLE WHERE _ _ _ _ _")

In the database, there are four fields (more in fact, but these are the pertinent ones): "TShirt1", "TShirt1Size", "TShirt2" and "TShirt2Size".

TShirt1 and TShirt2 both contain one of "RedCrew", "BlueSlim" or "GreyV"

TShirt1Size and TShirt2Size both contain one of "S", "M", "L" or "XL"

I want to know if I can create a query that will return the total numbers of each combination. *If I didn't have two fields*, it would be

```
SELECT TShirt, TShirtSize, count(*) FROM BookingsTable WHERE 1 GROUP BY TShirt, TShirtSize
```

so I would get results like

```
RedCrew, L, 2
BlueSlim, M, 4
```

etc.

Is there any way I can get the same, or similar output, but combining the results of TShirt1 and TShirt2?

EDIT: Apologies for the confusion. The actual table would be something like (typed not tested):

```
create table tshirt (
    TShirt_id int, 
    TShirt1 varchar(10), 
    TShirt1Size varchar(2), 
    TShirt2 varchar(10),
    TShirt2Size varchar(2)
);

insert into tshirt values (1, 'RedCrew', 'XL', 'BlueSlim', 'M'); 
insert into tshirt values (2, 'BlueSlim', 'L', 'RedCrew', 'L'); 
insert into tshirt values (3, 'GreyV', 'L', 'BlueSlim', 'M');
insert into tshirt values (4, 'BlueSlim', 'M', '', ''); 
insert into tshirt values (5, '', '', 'GreyV', 'L'); 
insert into tshirt values (6, 'BlueSlim', 'S', 'BlueSlim', 'L');
```

and the result set I would want (if my math is correct) would be:

```
BlueSlim, S, 1
BlueSlim, M, 4
BlueSlim, L, 2
GreyV, L, 2
RedCrew, L, 1
RedCrew, XL, 1
```

Comment: There are no fields. Tables have rows and columns :-). Now consider normalizing your schema.

Comment: omg, i got it... using only the select statement and where clause but i'm not sure how to get the lower `group by` to work with it...  i'm scared to post because i'm sure @AirThomas will downvote but i'm very proud of myself.  it was hard, lol...

Comment: Oh, but does there have to be a `group by` at the end?  or can it just be a `select` clause and a `from` clause only?  I wrote something that boils down to just a down to a single `select` and `from` but there's subqueries in the `select`... so that might break the rules.  No `where` or `group by`, though.

Comment: The system fills in SELECT at the start of the query and FROM (table) WHERE. As far as I know I can do whatever I want in there, although I have never tried subqueries. I may not even know the table name, I am not sure, I will see if it's known.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the various suggestions, however they were all outside of the limited scope I had. I ended up with the following query:

```
SELECT sum( if ((TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='S') OR (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='S'), if ( (TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='S') AND (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='S'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'RedCrew S',
sum( if ((TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='M') OR (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='M'), if ( (TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='M') AND (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='M'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'RedCrew M',
sum( if ((TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='L') OR (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='L'), if ( (TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='L') AND (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='L'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'RedCrew L',
sum( if ((TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='XL') OR (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='XL'), if ( (TShirt1='RedCrew' AND TShirt1Size='XL') AND (TShirt2='RedCrew' AND TShirt2Size='XL'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'RedCrew XL',
sum( if ((TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='S') OR (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='S'), if ( (TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='S') AND (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='S'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'BlueSlim S',
sum( if ((TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='M') OR (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='M'), if ( (TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='M') AND (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='M'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'BlueSlim M',
sum( if ((TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='L') OR (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='L'), if ( (TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='L') AND (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='L'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'BlueSlim L',
sum( if ((TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='XL') OR (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='XL'), if ( (TShirt1='BlueSlim' AND TShirt1Size='XL') AND (TShirt2='BlueSlim' AND TShirt2Size='XL'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'BlueSlim XL',
sum( if ((TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='S') OR (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='S'), if ( (TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='S') AND (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='S'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'GreyV S',
sum( if ((TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='M') OR (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='M'), if ( (TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='M') AND (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='M'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'GreyV M',
sum( if ((TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='L') OR (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='L'), if ( (TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='L') AND (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='L'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'GreyV L',
sum( if ((TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='XL') OR (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='XL'), if ( (TShirt1='GreyV' AND TShirt1Size='XL') AND (TShirt2='GreyV' AND TShirt2Size='XL'), 2, 1), 0)) AS 'GreyV XL' 
WHERE 1;
```

Which I generated in PHP with:

```
$tees=array('RedCrew','BlueSlim','GreyV');
$sizes=array('S','M','L','XL');
foreach ($tees as $t)
{
    foreach ($sizes as $s)
    {
        print "sum( if ((TShirt1='$t' AND TShirt1Size='$s') OR (TShirt2='$t' AND TShirt2Size='$s'), if ( (TShirt1='$t'  AND TShirt1Size='$s') AND (TShirt2='$t' AND TShirt2Size='$s'), 2, 1), 0)) AS '$t $s',<br>";
    }
}
```

It doesn't give exactly the right formatting for the answer, but it tells me what I need to know!

Comment: That's a clever work-around. Note that it's perfectly fine to [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), unless you'd like to wait a while to see if someone comes up with a better one.

Comment: I would prefer a generic query, but it may just not be possible with what I have to work with. I am asking whether it's possible to make the table not temporary so that I can do a union or join. Your solution would work, but I literally have a textbox after SELECT and before FROM and a textbox after WHERE, so I can't modify FROM. @gloomy.penguin might be on to something, but it's not quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you want...

```
create table #tshirt (
    tshirt_id int, 
    tshirt_name varchar(10), 
    tshirt_color varchar(15), 
    tshirt_size varchar(2)
) 

insert into #tshirt values (1, 'TShirt1', 'RedCrew', 'L') 
insert into #tshirt values (2, 'TShirt1', 'RedCrew', 'L') 
insert into #tshirt values (3, 'TShirt1', 'BlueSlim', 'M') 
insert into #tshirt values (4, 'TShirt1', 'BlueSlim', 'M') 
insert into #tshirt values (5, 'TShirt1', 'BlueSlim', 'M') 
insert into #tshirt values (6, 'TShirt1', 'BlueSlim', 'M') 

insert into #tshirt values (7, 'TShirt2', 'GreyV', 'S') 
insert into #tshirt values (8, 'TShirt2', 'BlueSlim', 'XL') 


SELECT tshirt_name, tshirt_color, tshirt_size, count(*) as ct
FROM #tshirt
GROUP BY tshirt_name, tshirt_color, tshirt_size
ORDER BY tshirt_name, tshirt_color, tshirt_size

--tshirt_name   tshirt_color   tshirt_size    ct
--TShirt1       BlueSlim       M              4
--TShirt1       RedCrew        L              2
--TShirt2       BlueSlim       XL             1
--TShirt2       GreyV          S              1


SELECT tshirt_name, count(*) as ct
FROM #tshirt
GROUP BY tshirt_name

--tshirt_name     ct
--TShirt1         6
--TShirt2         2
```

---

Based on my data and schema:

```
SELECT  tshirt_color, tshirt_size, count(*) as ct
FROM #tshirt
GROUP BY tshirt_color, tshirt_size
ORDER BY tshirt_color, tshirt_size

--tshirt_color   tshirt_size      ct
--BlueSlim       M              4
--BlueSlim       XL             1
--GreyV          S              1 
--RedCrew        L              2
```

---

**I seriously suggest changing your table schema**

```
create table #tshirt (
    TShirt_id int, 
    TShirt1 varchar(100), 
    TShirt1Size varchar(100), 
    TShirt2 varchar(100),
    TShirt2Size varchar(100)
);

insert into #tshirt values (1, 'RedCrew', 'XL', 'BlueSlim', 'M'); 
insert into #tshirt values (2, 'BlueSlim', 'L', 'RedCrew', 'L'); 
insert into #tshirt values (3, 'GreyV', 'L', 'BlueSlim', 'M');
insert into #tshirt values (4, 'BlueSlim', 'M', '', ''); 
insert into #tshirt values (5, '', '', 'GreyV', 'L'); 
insert into #tshirt values (6, 'BlueSlim', 'S', 'BlueSlim', 'L');  



select tshirt_desc, tshirt_size, COUNT(*) as ct
from  ( select  
               TShirt1 as tshirt_desc, 
               TShirt1Size as tshirt_size 
        from   #tshirt 
        union all
        select  
               TShirt2 as tshirt_desc, 
               TShirt2Size as tshirt_size 
        from   #tshirt ) as tshirt 
group by tshirt_desc, tshirt_size
order by tshirt_desc, tshirt_size

--tshirt_desc    tshirt_size     ct
--                               2
--BlueSlim       L               2
--BlueSlim       M               3
--BlueSlim       S               1
--GreyV          L               2
--RedCrew        L               1
--RedCrew        XL              1
```

---

try this..  (i had to use an online formatter b/c mine was very sloppy)

```
SELECT tshirt1     AS TShirt, 
       tshirt1size AS TShirtSize, 
       (SELECT ct 
        FROM   (SELECT tshirt, 
                       tshirtsize, 
                       Count(*) AS ct 
                FROM   (SELECT tshirt1     AS TShirt, 
                               tshirt1size AS TShirtSize 
                        FROM   #tshirt 
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT tshirt2     AS TShirt, 
                               tshirt2size AS TShirtSize 
                        FROM   #tshirt) AS tshirt 
                GROUP  BY tshirt, 
                          tshirtsize) AS inner_t 
        WHERE  inner_t.tshirt = outer_t.tshirt1 
               AND inner_t.tshirtsize = outer_t.tshirt1size) AS ct 
FROM   #tshirt AS outer_t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec024/8/0

you can easily remove the `outer_t` alias if you need to...

Comment: -1 for giving an answer based on a table design that you know doesn't match his existing table, when he plainly stated he only has limited `SELECT` privileges. And if you don't understand what he wants, why are you trying to answer his question?

Comment: because no one else is...? I'm kind of trying to understand right now and he's been editing the question in the process.  Plus, if he can only access the `select` clause, the can stick a whole query in there with the appropriate fields and it should work (a little hacky, though).  I still don't know exactly what result he wants - would you like to clarify for him?

Comment: This is a nice idea, but the second "nicely formatted" version, which fits in the template, doesn't fully work. With the example data, RedCrew L is missing in the result set

Comment: The outer_t alias makes the whole thing fit! I leave out the "FROM   #tshirt AS outer_t" part and let the system replace outer_t with the actual table name, which I was able to find by generating an error :)